# How To Customize a Magento Theme and Retain Its Source

Tags: magento, themes

Running Magento 1.7.0.2 (latest)

I downloaded a free theme and installed it - no problem.

I wish to start making subtle edits to it but I do not want to touch the source. I want to make the edits in a directory where they will render and override the base custom theme yet not get trashed if I were to upgrade the free theme should a newer version get released.

My theme is installed at:

```
.../app/design/frontend/default/the_free_theme/
../skin/frontend/default/the_free_theme/
```

What directory structure would I create to copy selected theme files from the custom theme so that they overrode the base file but would not get deleted in the event of an upgrade?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) In Magento admin: configuration -> design

in default type: the_free_theme

now in skin, templates and layouts fields, type "my_new_theme" (or what ever you want to call it).

now create new folders:

```
.../app/design/frontend/default/my_new_theme/
../skin/frontend/default/my_new_theme/
```

Any files you want to change from the template you copy into the new folder and they will override the base template files, keeping them in tact.

for example, if you want to change the heeader template:

copy .../app/design/frontend/default/the_free_theme/template/page/html/header.phtml

to .../app/design/frontend/default/my_new_theme/template/page/html/header.phtml

and then edit the new file. this will override the base template file.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. But I want to confirm with you that I am not talking about the out-of-the-box base theme from Magento itself. I am talking about downloading a free theme from a free template site out there. I want to install that free theme and keep it intact, letting it drive the look & feel and behavior of my site. Then I want to copy certain files from the downloaded/installed theme into <some directory> that I can edit and have override the free theme. I want to do this so when I update the free downloaded theme with a new release I can retain my edits. Is that what you are referring too?

Comment: Yes, that's why you add the_free_theme to the "default" field.
Magento will use this as the default/fallback theme instead of the default base theme.

Comment: I have not yet had a chance to try this out @Andrew. I have run into a number of issues with Magento in areas where I would have thought the product would be mature. It caused me to get active in the Community Forum and even issue a couple bug reports. I am beginning to get very concerned about the stability of the product. Not yet sure if I want to cut it off at this point and move on to 1 of the other 3 carts I short-listed too. Hoping to hear from the community on my reported issues, but the majority of the community feedback is not valuable and there is a ton of forum spam happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out how it's done, copy the downloaded theme into a new interface!

1)
Do this for both the skin and the design folder i.e
.../app/design/frontend/default/my_downloaded_theme/ -> .../app/design/frontend/myinterfacename/default

../skin/frontend/default/my_dowloaded_theme -> ../skin/frontend/myinterfacename/default

interfacename can be anything!

now, create a new theme folder both places (skin && design) under same parent folder as the new default theme you just copied.

In this case I call it the main folder.  The structure will look something like this:

........../frontend/myinterfacename/main

So under folder myinterfacename you should see a default folder and a main folder.

2)
go into admin into design and use myinterfacename/main as your default theme....

this folder is empty therefore it will fallback to the default of myinterfacename which is the downloaded theme you just copied.

Now, for anything you want to change, just copy from default to the new main folder and modify it from there!!!

Good luck!!!