# Magento edit responsive css to rearrange column

Tags: html, css, magento, flexbox

My site's product page is two column

col-main contains product and col-right sidebar displays some bocks like (related products,  ads)

These two columns works perfect in desktop but when the product page is viewed from mobile device the right column displays first. The users have to scroll down to view the product.

If you understand my problem eg: A user visits a product page from his mobile device and first thing it shows is the related products. visitors leave the site from there most visitors dont tend to scroll down.

if some one can help me make the col-main to appear first and col-right second.
down is my theme's main-responsive.css file

Theme Link: http://accessshopthemes.com/magento-themes/accessshop-lite/
Eg Page link (try resizing browser window): http://accessshopthemes.com/demo/access-shop/cute-2014-navy-stand-collar-ruffles-buttons-coat.html

```css
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .right-header-top .welcome.col-sm-3{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .right-header-top .col-sm-9{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-image {
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-right{
    width: 23%;
  }
  .block-content > img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box-left {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .box-left > img, .box-right > img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box-right{
    width: 24%;
  }
  .responsive-features-left{
    width: 65%;
  }
  .responsive-features-right{
    width: 30%;
  }
  .responsive-display-img > img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right-image > img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .imgresponsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .productimage label{
    top: 170px; 
  }
  .col-left {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col2-layout .col-main {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
  }
  .top-cart{
    border: none;
  }
  #sequence > .sequence-canvas li > .banner-container{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col3-layout .col-main {
    width: 44%;
}
  
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  header .col-sm-4, header .col-sm-6  {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header .col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-2{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
  .logo{
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
  .services{
    width: 49%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .services:nth-of-type(2n){
    border-right: none; 
  }
  .maincontent.col1-layout{
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .categories-search input[type="text"]{
    width: 240px !important;  
  }
  .product-options-bottom .add-to-links{
    position: static;
  }
  .related-items {
    margin-top: 36px;
  }
  .productimage > img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.display-onhover .add-to-links{
  top: 10px;
}
.display-onhover .actions{
  top: 92px;
}
.title{
    width: 90%;
  }
  .subtitle{
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col3-layout .col-main {
    width: 42%;
}
  
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  header, .maincontent, .brands, #before-footer, footer{
    padding: 0 1%;
  }
  #before-footer{
    padding: 10px 1%;
  }
  .col-sm-4.wow.slideInRight.animated {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
  .focus-content .col-sm-4{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right-links{
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .block-footer-bottom-right-links.pull-right, .block-copyright.pull-left{
    float: none !important;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .block-footer-bottom-right-links ul{
    float: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .header-top .col-sm-5{
    text-align: center;
  }
  .header-top .col-sm-7{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-8.pull-right{
   float: none;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
 }
/* .mini-products-list .product-details{
  text-align: center;
}*/
.navbar-form.navbar-right {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}
.col-sm-12.top-search {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
.col-sm-12.top-cart {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
.list-inline.pull-right.topcart {
  float: none !important;
}
.col-main{
  width: 100% !important;
}
.col-right.sidebar{
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.add-to-box{
  min-height: 150px;
}
.product-img-column{
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive-features-left{
  width: 100%;
}
.responsive-features-right{
  width: 100%;
}
.right-header-top{
  text-align: center;
}

.js #menu {
  display:none;
}

.product-options-bottom .add-to-links{
  position: absolute;
}
.imgresponsive{
  width: auto;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
.dropdown li {
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.level1.dropdown-menu{
  left: 0;
}
.col-left{
  width: 100%;
}
.products-grid .item{
  width: 100%;
}
.productimage > img{
  width: auto;
}
.maincontent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header .welcome-msg, .welcome{
  float: none;
}
.col3-layout .col-main {
    width: 98% !important;
}
.col2-layout .col-main {
    width: 98% !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li.parent > a:after{
  content: '';
}
}
@media (max-width: 640px){
  .newsletter-box .box-left, .newsletter-box .box-right{
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
  .newsletter-box .box-left{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  }
  .newsletter-box .box-right{
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  .banner{
    display: none;
  }
  .left-image{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .middle-text{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .services{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
  }
  .services:nth-of-type(4){
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .welcome.pull-left{
    display: block;
    float: none !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .right-header-top{
    padding: 0;
  }
  .categories-search select{
    width: 90px;
  }
  .categories-search input[type="text"]{
    width: 120px !important;
  }
  .custom-link{
    display: none;
  }
  .right-header-top {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sorter .amount, .sorter .sort-by, .sorter .limiter, .sorter .view-mode, .sorter .pages{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * @category    design
 * @package     accessshop_lite_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 AccessShop Themes (http://www.accessshopthemes.com)
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head'); ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices'); ?>
<header>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header'); ?>
</header>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider'); ?>
<div class="maincontent col2-layout">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs'); ?>
                <aside class="col-right sidebar">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right'); ?>
                </aside>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="brands">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home-block-brands'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="before-footer">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before-footer'); ?>
</section>
<footer id="footer">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer'); ?>
</footer>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML associated with it.

Comment: updated with link to example page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current markup, you can do the following:

1. Add a custom class `reorder` to the parent container of the three divs.
2. Assign flexible box layout the the parent container.
3. Target the mobile screen size layout using media queries and reorder them using `order` property.

Check the browser compatibility table for [**Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .reorder {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .col-main {
    order: 1;
  }
  .col-right {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 reorder">
  <div class="breadcrumbs">1</div>
  <aside class="col-right sidebar ">2</aside>
  <div class="col-main">3</div>
</div>
```

**Tested on your sample page for output:**

[image: Reordered columns]

Comment: Thank you very much for your responce, should i have to enter this in the main-responsive.css and the layout html(which i just added above). Kindly bare with since am not a pro.

Comment: No problem. I think it is better added in a custom file `custom.css` so that your changes are preserved even though Magento is upgraded. There should be a similar procedure for editing template file too. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500756/how-to-customize-a-magento-theme-and-retain-its-source

Comment: And also this: [**Mastering Magento editing**](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/07/mastering-magentos-templates-in-five-easy-steps-part-1)

Comment: You are the best. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Added style given above in the head and edited line 42 from

```html
<div class="col-md-12"> to <div class="col-md-12 reorder">
```

solved my issue. Very simple

```html
<?php
/**
 * @category    design
 * @package     accessshop_lite_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 AccessShop Themes (http://www.accessshopthemes.com)
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang(); ?>"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head'); ?>
    <style>
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
  .reorder {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .col-main {
    order: 1;
  }
  .col-right {
    order: 2;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices'); ?>
<header>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header'); ?>
</header>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider'); ?>
<div class="maincontent col2-layout">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 reorder">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs'); ?>
                <aside class="col-right sidebar">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right'); ?>
                </aside>
                <div class="col-main">
                
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="brands">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('home-block-brands'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="before-footer">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before-footer'); ?>
</section>
<footer id="footer">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer'); ?>
</footer>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```